# How to listen to incoming events in Android UIThread

Tags: android, multithreading, communication

Having read lots of snippets and tutorials, I'm still (or even more) confused about the road to take. I need a thread/backgroundtask, that listens for incoming events on a socket and report any incomings to the UIThread. What would be the preferred way to choose? Own thread or multitasking? Best way to transfer data to the main thread?

Thanx for any thoughts on the matter.

Regards,
Marcus

Considering your answers below, I've tried the following:

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


Handler handler = new Handler() {

    @Override
       public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            toastSomething();
      };
};

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    threadstarter();
}


protected void threadstarter() {

    super.onStart();

    Thread backgroundthread = new Thread(new WorkerThread(handler));
    backgroundthread.start();
}

public void toastSomething() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} }
```

An my runnable:

```
public class WorkerThread implements Runnable {

Handler messageHandler;

WorkerThread(Handler incomingHandler) {
    messageHandler = incomingHandler;
}

public void run() {

    while (true) {

        for (int i = 0; i <= 100000; i++) {
            // wait a moment
        }
        messageHandler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
    }
} }
```

My layout only holds an additional checkbox:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="CheckBox" />
```

Good thing is, the toast appears. Bad thing, the cehckbox is unresponsive and the app crashes pretty quick. Isn't that, how it should be done?

Edit: the msg in sendMessage in the WorkerThread seems to be the troublemaker as the exception says, the message is all read in use?

Comment: +1 for @paradx's answer. And there are some samples with service inside SDK folder, you can try them.

Comment: Your checkbox is unresponsive, beacuse `messageHandler.sendEmptyMessage(1)` runs all the time, and blocks the UI thread. Try replacing your `for` loop with `Thread.sleep(5000)` and  that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code, that's finally working:

UIThread:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public static final String LOG_TAG = "UIThread";

    Handler handler = new Handler() {

        @Override
           public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                toastSomething();
                //Log.v(LOG_TAG, "main thread");
          };
    };

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        threadstarter();
    }

    protected void threadstarter() {

        super.onStart();

        Thread backgroundthread = new Thread(new WorkerThread(handler));
        backgroundthread.start();
    }

    public void toastSomething() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

WorkerThread:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public static final String LOG_TAG = "UIThread";

    Handler handler = new Handler() {

        @Override
           public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                toastSomething();
                //Log.v(LOG_TAG, "main thread");
          };
    };

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        threadstarter();
    }

    protected void threadstarter() {

        super.onStart();

        Thread backgroundthread = new Thread(new WorkerThread(handler));
        backgroundthread.start();
    }

    public void toastSomething() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

HTH someone. Thanx to all for the input.

Answer (score 0):

only ways to communiacte with UIThread from background are

```
runOnUIThread(new Runnable {.// your ui stuff goes here.});

handler.post(new Runnable{.// your ui stuff goes here.});
```

i can't think of anything else.. these 2 are very handy at all situations..

in ru

Comment: so, if the new runnable would be a separate class, implementing the runnable interface and my handler is created in the uithread that posts the runnable, how can the runnable post a message to the handler?

Answer (score 0):

You can communicate like this from background thread to UIThread

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() 
{
@Override
public void run() {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
                public void run() {
                    progress.setProgress(value);
                }
            });
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the `AsyncTask` class, and post on the UI thread inside the `onPreExecute(...)`, `onPostExecute(...)`, or `onProgressUpdate(...)` methods.

Another way is to use a new thread for the background work, and post a `Runnable` to a `Handler`.

If you instantiate the `Handler` on the UI thread, then everything you post to the handler will run on the UI thread. If you instantiate the handler on the background thread then everything you post to the handler will run on the background thread.

Comment: sry, but I'm still hanging. I'd like to go for a separate class, extending runnable. in the main activity, I'd go for a new myrunnable and instantiate a new thread and giving myrunnable to it. how does the handler work in this scenario, I still don't get it.

Comment: You should write your Runnable as an anonymous inner class, or as an inner class in you activity, else you won't be able to access the UI thread. Or you could take a Handler as a parameter in you Runnable's constructor and create the Handler in your mainAtivity and pass it to your Runnable when you instantiate it.